# Python: Printing a variable with a float and then adding a £ sign

Tags: python

Whenever I go to print out a GBP sign followed by a number I get this error code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 65, in <module>
    print (u"\xA3" + total_cost)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

This is the code.

```
total_cost == 10
print (u"\xA3" + total_cost)
```

I would like for it to output £10.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Simplest would be to use `,` instead of `+` inside the `print` or then just cast the `total_cost` to string with `str(total_cost)`. If you want to control the number of digits printed, use f-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

`print (u"\xA3" + str(total_cost))`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the number to a string using the `str()` function. It's not very efficient for a lot of computations though so beware :)

```
print(u"\xA3" + str(total_cost))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print (u"\xA3", total_cost, sep='')
£10
```